# When I terminate the google-app-engine's HelloWorld project from PyDev, the python.exe isn't terminated

Tags: python, eclipse, google-app-engine, pydev

The issue is like this:

- I created a Google-App-Engine's HelloWorld demo supplied by PyDev in Eclipse, and then I just run the demo project, I browse the localhost:8080 and it succeeds.
- But then I stop the project and start it again (or just restart it)
  through the buttons, the browser couldn't show me a page from
  localhost:8080, the browser keeps asking for the response and
  couldn't get it.
- I've googled it for about 5 hours. And finally, I found where the
  issue lay on. First, when the helloworld project start, 2 python.exe process will be added into the taskmgr. When you terminate the project from the PyDev, there is
  no error sign there, but only 1 python.exe process was terminated and the other one still remains even if you close the Eclipse. So
  these python.exe still have the control of the port 8080, and the new
  instance of python.exe created by the relaunch action couldn't use
  the port 8080. So, the browser couldn't get a response back. If you
  keep doing relaunch the project, the number of python.exe in the
  tasklist may become 10+. I've tried use the Windows cmd to start the project and 2 process start when the start of the project and 2 process terminated when the terminate of the process.
- Changing the port 8080 which the project use to others couldn't solve
  the issue. If you start and stop by using the Google's client of
  Google-App-Engine. It just works well, there is no extra python.exe
  process remain in the tasklist.
- By the way, I've tried to update those software to the newest version
  for now and reinstall them. But the issue still exists.
- I've tried to use the pythonw.exe instead of python.exe as the
  interpreter, the issue still exists.

Here is some environment data below:

1. OS: Win7x64 SP1
2. Eclipse: 4.3
3. PyDev: 2.8.2
4. Google-App-Engine: 1.8.4
5. Python: 2.7.5 x86

According to those details I mentioned above, I could believe that the issue comes from the PyDev but I can't find the solution or the way to submit the issue to the PyDev project team.

Comment: Finally it works well on Ubuntu. I think this is the easiest way for me to solve the problem.